# Require JS is Not Working in Magento2

Tags: magento2

```
require(['naeem'], function($){
 $(document).ready( function() {
   alert("Page loaded.");
  });
});
```

File Save in `magento2\app\design\frontend\new\customtheme\web\js\naeem.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        slick: 'js/naeem'
    },
    deps: [
        "js/naeem"
    ],
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

File Save in `magento2\app\design\frontend\new\customtheme\require.js`

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: I don't get a alert message at home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding js via requirejs is the best way but not as you did

Here is a full example.

Supposing that your js file is: `myfile.js`

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/myfile'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/myfile.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert("Yesss, Page loaded.");
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 0):

Use below solution

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
     map: {
         '*': {
             'naeem': 'js/naeem'
         }
     }
};
```

Run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

And you can use your js from anywhere in Magento

```
require(['naeem'], function($){

});
```